# Compute the max and min daily from hourly data?

Tags: r

If I have this data:

```
   dat=structure(list(year = c(1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L
   ), DOY = c(144, 144.042, 144.083, 144.125, 144.167, 144.208), 
   time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), B = c(67, 7, 7, 
   0, 7, 6), gg = c(67, 7, 7, 
  0, 7, 6)),row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to compute the max and min per day of all columns and return

```
      year DOY  max.B  min.B  mean.B max.gg min.gg mean.gg
```

I have several columns not only B and gg

Comment: There is a syntax error in the input shown.  Also please show the expected output that would correspond to the input shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the followqing does what the question asks for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(day = strptime(paste(year, DOY), format = "%Y %j"),
         day = as.Date(day)) %>%
  select(-year, -DOY) %>%
  pivot_longer(-day) %>%
  group_by(day, name) %>%
  summarise(max = max(value), min = min(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = day, 
    names_from = name,
    names_glue = "{name}_{.value}",
    values_from = c(max, min)
  )
```

---

### Edit

To compute the means of `min` and `max`, assign the previous result to a variable `daily`, keep only the year/month in `day`, reshape to long format, group and compute the `value` column means. Then reshape back to wide format.

```
daily %>% 
  mutate(month = format(day, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  select(-day) %>%
  pivot_longer(-month) %>%
  mutate(name = sub("_.*$", "", name)) %>%
  group_by(month, name) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = month,
    names_from = name,
    names_glue = "{name}_{.value}",
    values_from = mean
  )
```

Comment: Thanks much. This is exactly what I want. Last thing please, how can we average the output per name par month?

Comment: @bicton Done, see the edit.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I meant: in your first answer, you computed the daily max and min for each name. Now we compute the monthly mean of these daily max and min for each name.

Comment: @bicton That much easier, then. Assign the result of the first code to `daily` and then run the one-liner `daily %>% mutate(across(-day, mean))`.

Comment: Thanks, that give one unique value for all months and years!

Comment: @bicton Sorry for the wrong code, I believe that now I've got it right.

Answer (score 1):

With data.table you can do:

```r
require(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[ ,
     .(min.B = min(B),
       max.B = max(B),
       mean.B = mean(B),
       min.gg = min(gg),
       max.gg = max(gg),
       mean.gg = mean(gg)),
     .(year, DOY) ]
```